# when I make a website, I check that site only with google chrome browser

Tags: browser, web

when I make a website, I check that site only with google chrome browser, and later when I want to check it with mozilla browser, it doesn't open the same as in google chrome.
How can I make so that my website could be seen in all the browsers similarly.

Comment: `I check that site only with google chrome browser` - what? doesn't even make sense...

Answer (score 0):

there is two components in Browser. The layout Engine and the Javascript Engine. Let's talk about the Layout engine... which is your case. Each browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome...) have different Layout Engine so it Might render your view slightly differently. Let's say that in chrome you write down that each paragraphs  have the color tomato

```
<style type="text/css">
p{
  color:tomatoe;
}
</style>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Than each browser might show (render) this tomato color in a different shade of tomatoe color.
ex in Firefox tomato = #FF6347; in Chrome it might be #FF6341.

For the Layout Engine you can you some tools such as [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

That's a part of your question.... you will have to post the html element that doesn't look the same.